# 403 Forbidden error when trying to call PowerBI's EXPORT API using PowerBI Embedded APIs

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I'm writing a website by PowerBI emmbedded, using apis of powerBI services,I want try to call this [EXPORT API](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/power-bi/reports/export-to-file)

But I got an error "403Forbidden". Now I have a Pro license, Is it possible that it's an license issue, or need to upgrade? Thanks.

I try to call the api by postman, but still got "403Forbidden", I hope call this API successfully.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Mb82.png)

Comment: 403 "Forbidden" means that nobody is allowed to access the resource you are trying to access, ever. So as long as this status code is correct, it is not a license error, and nothing that you can fix. 401 errors mean you are not authorised or authenticated; these errors can be fixed by supplying the right authorisation. But not 403.

Comment: @Simon, Refer to this documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/power-bi/developer/embedded/troubleshoot-rest-api#api-call-returns-403 and verify if anyone of those may be the reason

Comment: If that doesn't resolve the issue, you need to reframe your question with more details.